# Errors while running hadoop

Tags: hadoop, localhost

```
haduser@user-laptop:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/input 
/user/haduser/input

11/12/14 14:21:00 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:02 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:03 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:04 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:05 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:06 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:07 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. -Already tried 7 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:08 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s).

11/12/14 14:21:09 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s).

Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I am getting the above errors when I'm trying to copy files from `/tmp/input` to `/user/haduser/input` even though the file `/etc/hosts` contain entry for localhost.
When the `jps command` is run, the `TaskTracker` and the `namenode` are not listed.

What could be the problem? Please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar issues - Actually Hadoop was binding to IPv6.
Then I Added - "`export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` " to `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh`

Hadoop was binding to IPv6 even when I had disabled IPv6 on my system.
Once I added it to env, started working fine.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do ssh to your local system using the IP, in this case:

$ ssh 127.0.0.1

Once you are able to do the ssh successfully. Run the below command to know the list of open ports

~$ lsof -i

look for a listening connector with name: localhost:< PORTNAME > (LISTEN)

copy this < PORTNAME > and replace the existing value of port number in  tag of fs.default.name property in your core-site.xml in the hadoop conf folder

save the core-site.xml, this should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

NameNode (NN) maintains the namespace for HDFS and it should be running for filesystem operations on HDFS. Check the logs why the NN hasn't started. TaskTracker is not required for operations on HDFS, only NN and DN are sufficient. Check the http://goo.gl/8ogSk and http://goo.gl/NIWoK tutorials on how to setup Hadoop on a single and multi node.

Comment: I have followed the same link for installation. But still getting the errors.

Comment: I wasn't able to format the namenode using the command 
$ bin/hadoop namenode -format. Is that the reason why the namenode is not starting?

Comment: That could be the reason. As mentioned earlier check the logs.

Answer (score 1):

All the files in the bin are exectuables. Just copy the command and paste it in the terminal. Make sure the address is right, i.e. the user must be replaced by something. That would do the trick.