# Hadoop connect error with put/copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop, connection, localhost

I was following a [tutorial to install hadoop](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/).
Now I am stuck at the

> Copy local example data to HDFS

step.

I get the following connection error:

```
<12/10/26 17:29:16 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 0 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:17 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 1 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:18 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 2 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:19 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 3 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:20 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 4 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 5 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:22 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 6 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 7 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 8 time(s).
12/10/26 17:29:25 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:54310. Already tried 9 time(s).
Bad connection to FS. command aborted. exception: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

This is pretty much the same as in [Errors while running hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501781/errors-while-running-hadoop)

The point now is, I have disabled the ivp6, as described there and in the above tutorial, but it doesn't help. Is there something I have been missing?

I repeated the tutorial on a second machine with a freshly installed Ubuntu and compared it step by step. It turned out, there was some bug in the `bashrc` configuration of the `hduser`. Afterwards it worked fine...

Answer (score 4):

I get the exact error message if I try to do `Hadoop fs <anything>` when the DataNode/NameNode aren't running, so I would guess the same is happening for you.

Type `jps` in your terminal. If everything is running, it should look like:

```
16022 DataNode
16524 Jps
15434 TaskTracker
15223 JobTracker
15810 NameNode
16229 SecondaryNameNode
```

I would wager that you're DataNode or NameNode isn't running. If anything is missing from jps's print out, start it again.

Comment: The nodes had been running, so that wasn't the problem. But I found the trouble by now,thanks for the help anyway through!

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

after the whole configuration give this command

hadoop namenode -formate

and the start all services by this command

start-all.sh

this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your etc/hadoop/core-site.xml. check the value for fs.default.name
   It should be as shown below.
   {


   fs.default.name
   hdfs://localhost:54310


   }
2. after the whole configuration give this command

hadoop namenode -format

3. the start all services by this command

start-all.sh

this will solve your problem .

Your namenode may be in safe mode ,run bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave or bin/hadoop dsfadmin -safemode leave 
then follow step - 2 and step -3